# Default root user file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, root

Hi I’m setting up a vps for the first time and my host sets me up as a user with sudo by default. When I create a folder/file with sudo the permissions are set to x00 and I can’t even then cd into that directory without changing to root or changing permissions with chmod. Is this the normal default permissions for folders/files created with sudo and can I change the default?

Comment: Welcome to SO! For non-programming Linux questions, check out our sister sites [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). The setting you're looking for is the "umask", and it may be getting its value from `/etc/login.defs` or `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Perfect answer thank you. Umask was set to 077 in login.defs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.